# Euclid's division algorithm (to find HCF ) is there a better way?

Tags: python

```
#HCF
#input

C = int(input("the bigger number:" ))
D = int(input("the smaller number:" ))

#division
N = "="
M = "x"
A = "+"


#i don't know if I can add this to the while loop
Q = C//D
S = C%D
print (C,N,D,M,Q,A,S)
E = S
s = D
D = C
#Euclid's division algorithm
while S != 0:
    Q = s//E
    S = s%E
    print(s, N,E, M, Q, A, S)
    s = E
    if S == 0:
        print ("HCF =",E)
else :
    E = S
```

**is there a better way of writing this ?**
if there is a syntax I am using incorrectly pls tell.

I don't know why I can't post this it's showing your post is mostly code pls explain ignore this last part it's only so this problem goes away.

Comment: the minimum length is there for you to _explain your question_. This is especially important when all your variable names are single letters so nobody can possibly have any idea what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: [Here are several methods](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Python)  of finding the Euclidean division algorithm (aka gcd) in Python (and other languages) for compariso

Comment: What's the purpose of `N = "="` and such - other than making your code more unreadable?

Comment: Your code reports incorrect results.  For instance `C = 498, D = 222` your code prints `HCF = 54`, while it's actually 6.

Comment: Thank you for all your input I will try to make my code more readable next time. Thanks

Comment: I have made my code 12 lines long and DarrylG I did not get (498 and 222 = 54 ) error when I checked and thank you all for giving the tip to make my code more presentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way of writing your code

- Corrects an error in posted code which provides incorrect results
- Uses variables from an algorithm to provide a reference for variable names
- Uses string interpolation to show formula

**Euclidean Algorithm**

[image: Euclidean Algorithm]

[Reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html)

**Implementation**

a, b, q, r corresponds to a, b, qi, ri in the algorithm

```
def euclidean_algorithm(a, b):
  " Displays iterations of the euclidean algorithm "
  if b > a:
    # swap if necessary 
    # to ensure a is the larger number
    a, b = b, a

  while b:
    q = a // b
    r = a - q*b
    print(f'{a} = {q} x {b} + {r}') # use string interpolation to show formula
    a, b = b, r
    
  print(f'HCF = {a}')

  return a
```

**Usage**

```
a = int(input('First number: '))
b = int(input('Second number: '))
euclidean_algorithm(a, b)
```

**Output**

```
First number: 498
Second number: 222
498 = 2 x 222 + 54
222 = 4 x 54 + 6
54 = 9 x 6 + 0
HCF = 6
```

Comment: thank you, this helps me understand a lot my first coding so thanks a lot :)